# Upload Large File in SharePoint Using REST or JSOM for Office 365

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint-online, office365api

Hi I am looking for file upload API or is there any custom code is available or some logic which i can apply to Upload large file. i know we can use chunk files. but i don't aware it how we can chunk in client side and merge it in server side for office 365. Please provide some help.
i go through this example.
https://gist.github.com/beckettkev/cbb4f1e594ef648e06b6287d6af39138

but it is not working for me. i am able to make a chunk of files.
now i have two options .

1- merge all chunks which is basically a array buffer object and send it to office 365 upload service.
2- send all chunks individually and make a file in server. but again problem how to merge file in server.

please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing lots of research. I made below code for sharepoint online. its working using request executor. I tried 500MB file it is working fine for me. intenionally made it minified. but you can use it as it is.

```js
"use strict";var FileUploadService=function(){function e(){}var t=e.prototype;return t.siteUrl=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,t.siteRelativeUrl="/"!=_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl?_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl:"",t.fileUpload=function(e,t,n){var r=this;return new Promise(function(o,i){r.createDummyFile(n,t).then(function(a){var u=new FileReader,l=0,c=e.size,s=parseInt(1e6)>c?Math.round(.8*c):parseInt(1e6),f=[];u.readAsArrayBuffer(e),u.onload=function(e){for(;l<c;)l+s>c&&(s=c-l),f.push({offset:l,length:s,method:r.getUploadMethod(l,s,c)}),l+=s;var a=c/f.length/c*100;if(f.length>0){var u=r.guid();r.uploadFile(e.target.result,u,t,n,f,0,0,a,o,i)}}})})},t.createDummyFile=function(e,t){var n=this;return new Promise(function(r,o){var i="decodedurl='"+n.siteRelativeUrl+"/"+t+"'",a=n.siteUrl+"/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath("+i+")/files/add(overwrite=true, url='"+e+"')";n.executeAsync(a,n.convertDataBinaryString(2),{accept:"application/json;odata=verbose"}).then(function(e){return r(!0)}).catch(function(e){return o(e)})})},t.convertDataBinaryString=function(e){for(var t="",n=new Uint8Array(e),r=0;r<n.byteLength;r++)t+=String.fromCharCode(n[r]);return t},t.executeAsync=function(e,t,n){var r=this;return new Promise(function(o,i){new SP.RequestExecutor(r.siteUrl).executeAsync({url:e,method:"POST",body:t,binaryStringRequestBody:!0,headers:n,success:function(e){return o(e)},error:function(e){return i(e.responseText)}})})},t.uploadFileChunk=function(e,t,n,r,o,i){var a=this;return new Promise(function(i,u){var l=0===r.offset?"":",fileOffset="+r.offset,c=a.siteUrl+"/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('"+a.siteRelativeUrl+"/"+t+"/"+n+"')/"+r.method+"(uploadId=guid'"+e+"'"+l+")";a.executeAsync(c,o,{Accept:"application/json; odata=verbose","Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"}).then(function(e){return i(e)}).catch(function(e){return u(e)})})},t.uploadFile=function(e,t,n,r,o,i,a,u,l,c){var s=this,f=this.convertFileToBlobChunks(e,a,o[i]);this.uploadFileChunk(t,n,r,o[i],f,a).then(function(f){var d=i===o.length-1;i+=1;d||Math.round(i*u);i<o.length?s.uploadFile(e,t,n,r,o,i,a,u,l,c):l(f)}).catch(function(e){console.log("Error in uploadFileChunk! "+e),c(e)})},t.getUploadMethod=function(e,t,n){return e+t+1>n?"finishupload":0===e?"startupload":e<n?"continueupload":null},t.convertFileToBlobChunks=function(e,t,n){var r=e.slice(n.offset,n.offset+n.length);return this.convertDataBinaryString(r)},t.guid=function(){function e(){return Math.floor(65536*(1+Math.random())).toString(16).substring(1)}return e()+e()+"-"+e()+"-"+e()+"-"+e()+"-"+e()+e()+e()},e}();function UploadFile(e){var t=e.target.files;0!=t.length&&FileUploadService.prototype.fileUpload(t[0],"UploadLibrary",t[0].name).then(function(e){console.log("File Uploaded Successfully")}).catch(function(e){console.log(e)})}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input class="upload form-control" id="DocUploader" placeholder="Upload file" type="file" onchange="UploadFile(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the above JSOM code provided by Negi Rox, It does not seem to work with SharePoint Hosted Add-In when used in SharePoint Online/Office 365. Getting following error:

```
"{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.FileStore.ErrorExceptionTag","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Error=Value=CobaltAllZerosDetected, Tag=0x0121d3da"}}}"
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34631049)

Comment: its a rest api code you just need to make sure you are getting a context.

Answer (score -2):

Check below official sample.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint

```
public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File UploadFileSlicePerSlice(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string fileName, int fileChunkSizeInMB = 3)
        {
            // Each sliced upload requires a unique ID.
            Guid uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();

            // Get the name of the file.
            string uniqueFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            // Ensure that target library exists, and create it if it is missing.
            if (!LibraryExists(ctx, ctx.Web, libraryName))
            {
                CreateLibrary(ctx, ctx.Web, libraryName);
            }
            // Get the folder to upload into. 
            List docs = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
            ctx.Load(docs, l => l.RootFolder);
            // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
            ctx.Load(docs.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            // File object.
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile;

            // Calculate block size in bytes.
            int blockSize = fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024;

            // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
            ctx.Load(docs.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();


            // Get the size of the file.
            long fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;

            if (fileSize <= blockSize)
            {
                // Use regular approach.
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fileInfo.ContentStream = fs;
                    fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
                    fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
                    uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
                    ctx.Load(uploadFile);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
                    return uploadFile;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Use large file upload approach.
                ClientResult<long> bytesUploaded = null;

                FileStream fs = null;
                try
                {
                    fs = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                        Byte[] lastBuffer = null;
                        long fileoffset = 0;
                        long totalBytesRead = 0;
                        int bytesRead;
                        bool first = true;
                        bool last = false;

                        // Read data from file system in blocks. 
                        while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

                            // You've reached the end of the file.
                            if (totalBytesRead == fileSize)
                            {
                                last = true;
                                // Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
                                lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                                Array.Copy(buffer, 0, lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }

                            if (first)
                            {
                                using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    // Add an empty file.
                                    FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                                    fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
                                    fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
                                    fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
                                    uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

                                    // Start upload by uploading the first slice. 
                                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                                    {
                                        // Call the start upload method on the first slice.
                                        bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
                                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                                        // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
                                        fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                                    }

                                    // You can only start the upload once.
                                    first = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Get a reference to your file.
                                uploadFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + uniqueFileName);

                                if (last)
                                {
                                    // Is this the last slice of data?
                                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(lastBuffer))
                                    {
                                        // End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
                                        uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                                        // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
                                        return uploadFile;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                                    {
                                        // Continue sliced upload.
                                        bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                                        // Update fileoffset for the next slice.
                                        fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } // while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (fs != null)
                    {
                        fs.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Update:

Check below sample for JS solution.

http://sharepointcookies.com/2017/02/programmatically-uploading-large-files-client-side-to-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: i am talking about REST and JSOM not Csom

Comment: same link i have given in my description

Comment: I haven't test the code, while the logic should work. the core logic is construct the REST api endpoint like api/web
    /getfilebyserverrelativeurl('file')
    /continueupload(uploadId=guid'GUID',fileOffset=8388608) as official guideline. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileContinueUpload